# Stored procedure to store current year and reset the other field

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I had the table with just two fields like

```
Act nvarchar(50)
Cnt int
```

And have the stored procedure to update/insert the records, If there is new Act set the cnt to 1 and if there is a Act already increment them cnt+1. And the stored procedure looks like

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_INSU] 
 @act_TT AS act_TT READONLY

 AS
 BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 BEGIN TRANSACTION;

 MERGE dbo.[c_Act] prj
 USING @act_TT tt
 ON prj.Act = tt.Act
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET prj.Cnt=prj.Cnt+1
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (Act,Cnt)
 VALUES (tt.Act, 1);

 select * from dbo.[c_Act] ca Join @act_TT TT On  ca.Act = TT.Act;
 COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Now I need to add in the table a field called year which should store just the current year. I am not sure how to store the year, I know the Datetime datatype which stores everything dd,mm,yyyy and time. Also if the year is changed wewill need to reset the Cnt to 1 irrespective of the Act. Here I am not sure what datatype the year field and how to check for the year and reset the counter

Comment: I would use `INT` for year and store it in format of `YYYY`, to get the current year use `SELECT YEAR(GETDATE())` .

Comment: @M.Ali but here how do we check if the year is next then we reset the cnt to 1 again. How can I check that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `INT` for year and store it in format of `YYYY`, to get the current year use `SELECT YEAR(GETDATE())` . Your Merge statement would look something like.....

```
 MERGE dbo.[c_Act] prj
 USING @act_TT tt ON prj.Act = tt.Act
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
     SET prj.Cnt = prj.Cnt+1
        ,prj.YearCol = YEAR(GETDATE())
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
 INSERT (Act   ,  Cnt , YearCol         )
 VALUES (tt.Act,    1 , YEAR(GETDATE()) );
```

Comment: Being pedantic, it is more efficient to use a smallint for Year.

Comment: how do I set the format of the field in the SQL server. When I right clicked on the table and gave the New Column it it is not showing the format just the datatype and Allow Nulls

Comment: But here how do we check if the year is next then we reset the cnt to 1 again. How can I check that

Answer (score 1):

> how do we check if the year is next then we reset the cnt to 1 again

```
MERGE dbo.[c_Act] prj
 USING @act_TT tt ON prj.Act = tt.Act
 WHEN MATCHED AND prj.YearCol = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1 THEN UPDATE 
     SET prj.Cnt = 1
        ,prj.YearCol = YEAR(GETDATE())
 WHEN MATCHED AND prj.YearCol != YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1 THEN UPDATE 
     SET prj.Cnt = prj.Cnt+1
        ,prj.YearCol = YEAR(GETDATE())
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
 INSERT (Act   ,  Cnt , YearCol         )
 VALUES (tt.Act,    1 , YEAR(GETDATE()) );
```

OR

```
MERGE dbo.[c_Act] prj
 USING @act_TT tt ON prj.Act = tt.Act
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
     SET prj.Cnt = CASE WHEN prj.YearCol = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1 THEN 1 ELSE prj.Cnt+1 END
        ,prj.YearCol = YEAR(GETDATE())
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
 INSERT (Act   ,  Cnt , YearCol         )
 VALUES (tt.Act,    1 , YEAR(GETDATE()) );
```